# Ubuntu 22.04 fancontrol & i8k not working

Tags: fan, overheating, temperature, lm-sensors

I have Dell Latitude 7480 running Ubuntu 22.04, and I tried installing `fancontrol` and `i8kutils` because my fan is simply not working, but after running `pwmconfig` I got following message:

```
Found the following devices:
   hwmon0 is AC
   hwmon1 is acpitz
   hwmon2 is BAT0
   hwmon3 is nvme
   hwmon4 is coretemp
   hwmon5 is dell_smm
   hwmon6 is pch_skylake
   hwmon7 is iwlwifi_1

Found the following PWM controls:
   hwmon5/pwm1           current value: 0

Giving the fans some time to reach full speed...
Found the following fan sensors:
   hwmon5/fan1_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!

There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0.
Make sure you have a 3-wire fan connected.
You may also need to increase the fan divisors.
See doc/fan-divisors for more information.
```

After running `i8kctl fan 1 1` I get -1 and 1, but then after 3 seconds of spinning second fan stops. I have `i8k` and `lm-sensors` installed, after hour of work but this happens:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +68.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +68.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +69.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

dell_smm-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 6600 RPM)
temp1:        +66.0°C  
temp2:        +39.0°C  
temp3:        +31.0°C  
temp4:        +27.0°C
```